# Which foreign currency has had the least amount of inflation over the last 50 years?

Tags: inflation, currency, foreign-exchange

I found this table that lists currency exchange rates relative to the US dollar. https://fx.sauder.ubc.ca/etc/USDpages.pdf

I noticed some currencies have increased in value relative to the dollar and some have decreased in value relative to the dollar.

It seems that some currencies have held their value better than others.

I am curious to know which currencies have been least affected by inflation over the past fifty years.

Comment: The fact that some currencies depreciated more than others against the USD may or may not have something to do with inflation. Other factors may be at play. Are you asking for a list of least affected currencies? In that case there isn't a canonical one - such a list will require some analysis. Or are you asking about an analysis?

Answer (score -1):

What have you tried so far? Inflation is computed in essentially all countries and usually also freely available on the respective website. E.g. [FRED](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/JPNCPIALLMINMEI#0) will allow you to get the data for many countries in one go.

[image]

You can for example also find good data at the [World Bank](http://wdi.worldbank.org/table/4.16#) for example, which offers good API capabilities. E.g, CPI for all available countries can be pulled with [WorldBankData](https://github.com/4gh/WorldBankData.jl) from [Julia](https://julialang.org/) or [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WDI/index.html) with the following lines in Julia:

```
using WorldBankData
wdi("FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG", "all", 1973, 2023)
```

This pulls all available CPI data in one go for all countries; 266 according to

```
unique(wdi("FP.CPI.TOTL.ZG", "all", 1973, 2023)[!,"country"])
```

Comment: this is not an answer but comment